# Data sense says I've used far more data than Verizon

Tags: data-usage, datasense

I just got a Lumia Icon 2 weeks ago.  During that time, Data Sense states I have used 2GB of data, while Verizon says .17GB.  I do most of my data usage on wi-fi and it almost seems as if Data Sense is including the wi-fi traffic as cellular data.  I am on WP8 and haven't updated to 8.1 yet.

What could account for this ridiculous discrepancy in measurements?

Comment: Have you set a limit? How does the split show on the "usage" tab in data sense?

Comment: Yeah, I set a limit and it actually worked when it thought it had reached the limit.  However, including wi-fi in that limit is useless to me since I'm only concerned with limiting my cellular data use.

Comment: My Lumia 1020 (running 8.0) tells my 1.7 Gb remaining on the live tile; which matches my network provider's figure, and my usage this month (306 Mb of 2048 Mb mobile). My 237 Mb of WiFi this month is apparently not included in the usage, so I'm not clear what you're seeing that's wrong?

Comment: @BBlake Is Data Sense telling you that you've used 2 GB of data *total*, or 2 GB of cellular data + however much on Wi-Fi? Maybe post a screenshot of exactly what you're seeing on your phone?

Comment: I have the set limit at 2GB of data.  It shut off my data and reported that I had 35MB of data remaining out of 2GB.  Just as it should do.  I looked at the usage page and it said I had used 1.97GB of cellular data and 16.13GB of wi-fi.  So it's measuring by what it believes is cellular data.    The My Verizon app and the Verizon website both say that over the same time period, I have used roughly 240MB of cellular data.  It's weird.

Comment: Is it possible that your monthly reset date doesn't match the date when your carrier resets your data usage? Other than that, I'm not sure what could be the problem, Data Sense has always been pretty reliable for me.

Comment: Are you using the same cut date as they?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, data sense measures both data usage - Cell and WiFi. In the new WP 8.1 this is clearly separated as you can see in the screenshot and if I remember correctly (haven't used WP 8.0 for a while) it counts both of them as well but without the separation

[image]

Comment: Ah, if that's the case, it's useless for me in 8.0 to set limit.  Planning to update to 8.1 this weekend anyway, so that should be better.

Comment: Data Sense in WP 8.0 also counts cellular and Wi-Fi data separately.